# Update newly added column according to foreign key in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I, after altering my table that was already filled with data, update the new column with values according to a previously existing foreign key ID.

Example:

Let's say I have the table **CarSales**, where I group sales quantities either by individual cars or by car type:

```
ID | CarID | CarType  | Quantity | SaleDate
1  | 1     | NULL     | 2        | <some date>
2  | 2     | NULL     | 3        | <some date>
3  | 2     | NULL     | 1        | <some date>
4  | NULL  | 'Trucks' | 12       | <some date>
...
```

**CarID** is a foreign key connect to the table **Cars**:

```
CarID | Color  | PistonMotion
1     | 'Blue' | V
2     | 'Gray' | V
3     | 'Pink' | Linear
4     | 'Blue' | Linear
...
```

Then I decide I also need to group sales quantities by piston motion, so I add a new column **PistonMotion** to **CarSales**:

```
ID | CarID | CarType  | PistonMotion | Quantity | SaleDate
1  | 1     | NULL     | NULL         | 2        | <some date>
2  | 2     | NULL     | NULL         | 3        | <some date>
3  | 2     | NULL     | NULL         | 1        | <some date>
4  | NULL  | 'Trucks' | NULL         | 12       | <some date>
...
```

Now, **CarSales** is already full of data (let's say I have thousands of rows), but I need to update **PistonMotion** for each row in the table according to **CarID** on the same row as a one-time action. As I want to group both **CarID** and **CarType** along with **PistonMotion** in the **CarSales** table I don't want to simply do a JOIN query to the **Cars** table in the future. I know I will not be able to update **PistonMotion** on the rows where **CarID** is NULL, but that doesn't matter, since these are not my actual tables, so please disregard from that.

The question is simply: what query do I need in order to update **PistonMotion** in **CarSales** so that it is equal to **PistonMotion** in **Cars** where the same **CarID** is shared?

Comment: Why do you want to add this column to `CarSales` if it's already available in `Cars`?

Comment: Like I already mentioned, these are not my real tables, I just made a very simplified example. The real situation is way more complex and I do not want to go into why I need to do this.

Comment: It's simple join to update. You can see in answer below. But, simplified or not, this is bad design idea. What about future rows? You will need to insert same data in two tables. What if `PistonMotion` changes in `Cars`? As simple the update is, it's just as simple to get the needed data from other table when you need it.

Comment: Because sometimes there is no `CarID` in the `CarSales` table, but you still need to be able to group by both `CarType` and `PistonMotion`. I realize however that I should leave `PistonMotion` as `NULL` where there is a `CarID` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an update with an inner join:

```
UPDATE CS
Set PistonMotion = C.PistonMotion
from CarSales CS inner join Cars C on C.CarID=CS.CarID
```